# Is there something akin to context manager so that there is no need to run close-input-port?

Tags: scheme, port, racket

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(require net/url racket/port)
(require (planet neil/html-parsing:3:0))

(define p (get-pure-port (string->url "https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping")))
(define my-html (port->string p))
(close-input-port p)
```

Is there another way of rewriting the above code so that there is no need to explicitly
instruct `(close-input-port p)`?
I have in mind something similar `call-with-input-file` that deals with closing
the port once the job of reading the file done (akin to [context managers in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use [`call/input-url`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Furl..rkt%29._call%2Finput-url%29%29):

```lisp
(define my-html
   (call/input-url (string->url "https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
                   get-pure-port port->string))
```

which opens a port from a URL using the given connection function, calls a handler function with that port, and closes the port before returning the handler's return values.

Many Scheme and Racket-specific function categories that open ports have equivalents, like the `call-with-input-file` like I used in an answer to another of your questions.